# Is there a numpy method to create a 2D array from the addition of two 1D arrays?

Tags: numpy

Basically, `s_{i,j} = a_i + b_j`

if `n=len(a)` and `m=len(b)`, then `s.shape` is `(n,m)`. Thus, the addition above is not commutative.

It involves some hocus pocus:

```
s = np.tile(a.reshape(n,1),m).reshape(n,m) + np.tile(b,n).reshape(n,m)
```

but I was wondering if there's already some method in numpy for this. I could not find it.

Comment: Use `a[:,np.newaxis] + b` to leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there actually is. `numpy` ufuncs have an `outer` method:

```
s = np.add.outer(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Outer or broadcasting?

## TLDR

In my test, broadcasting is better.

## Speed

```py
v1 = np.random.random((1_000))
v2 = np.random.random((1_000))

%timeit np.add.outer(v1, v2)
%timeit v1[:, np.newaxis] + v2

# 9.81 µs ± 2.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 7.95 µs ± 756 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each
```

Both code run almost the same, but `v1[:, np.newaxis] + v2` might be faster(?)

## Numba

```py
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def f1(v1, v2):  # throw error
    return np.add.outer(v1, v2)
def f2(v1, v2):  # works
    return v1[:, np.newaxis] + v2
```

The `v1[:, np.newaxis] + v2` is Numba compatible.

### Note:

`v1[:, np.newaxis] + v2` == `v1[:, None] + v2`.